# How to sync data form redshift to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-data-pipeline

Is there a cloud-formation template for creating data pipeline to sync data from redshift to Dynamo-DB?

Thanks,
Vinod.

Comment: Do you know whether such a transfer is possible (even configured manually)? Looking through the Data Pipeline user guide it _seems_ like you could export from Redshift using `SqlDataNode` and there seems to be the ability to "import DynamoDB backups" from S3. However, you'll need to experiment whether these will work as you expect. I suggest trying such a configuration manually before automating it through CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes, I have tried this manually and it works.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you try to create the CloudFormation template and let us know if you have any specific issues. I normally create templates by copying the code samples from the documentation and customizing it as necessary.